# Tokenizing sentences a special way

Tags: python, huggingface-transformers, huggingface-datasets

```
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
from datasets import load_dataset
from transformers import BertTokenizer

test_files = [join('./test/', f) for f in listdir('./test') if isfile(join('./test', f))]

dataset = load_dataset('json', data_files={"test": test_files}, cache_dir="./.cache_dir")
```

After running the code, here output of `dataset["test"]["abstract"]`:

```
[['eleven politicians from 7 parties made comments in letter to a newspaper .',
  "said dpp alison saunders had ` damaged public confidence ' in justice .",
  'ms saunders ruled lord janner unfit to stand trial over child abuse claims .',
  'the cps has pursued at least 19 suspected paedophiles with dementia .'],
 ['an increasing number of surveys claim to reveal what makes us happiest .',
  'but are these generic lists really of any use to us ?',
  'janet street-porter makes her own list - of things making her unhappy !'],
 ["author of ` into the wild ' spoke to five rape victims in missoula , montana .",
  "` missoula : rape and the justice system in a college town ' was released april 21 .",
  "three of five victims profiled in the book sat down with abc 's nightline wednesday night .",
  'kelsey belnap , allison huguet and hillary mclaughlin said they had been raped by university of montana football '
  'players .',
  "huguet and mclaughlin 's attacker , beau donaldson , pleaded guilty to rape in 2012 and was sentenced to 10 years .",
  'belnap claimed four players gang-raped her in 2010 , but prosecutors never charged them citing lack of probable '
  'cause .',
  'mr krakauer wrote book after realizing close friend was a rape victim .'],
 ['tesco announced a record annual loss of £ 6.38 billion yesterday .',
  'drop in sales , one-off costs and pensions blamed for financial loss .',
  'supermarket giant now under pressure to close 200 stores nationwide .',
  'here , retail industry veterans , plus mail writers , identify what went wrong .'],
 ...,
 ['snp leader said alex salmond did not field questions over his family .',
  "said she was not ` moaning ' but also attacked criticism of women 's looks .",
  'she made the remarks in latest programme profiling the main party leaders .',
  'ms sturgeon also revealed her tv habits and recent image makeover .',
  'she said she relaxed by eating steak and chips on a saturday night .']]
```

[image]

I would like that each sentence to have this structure of tokenizing. How can I do such thing using huggingface? In fact, I think I have to flatten each list of the above list to get a list of strings and then tokenize each string.

Comment: Yes just flatte the tokenizer output.